# Get data from pivot table in view laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem with data of relationship many to many, first i will put my models and controllers, i use laravel 5.3

**Model Lists Addresses**

```
class ListsAddresses extends Model
{
protected $table = "addresses";

protected $fillable = ['state', 'city', 'street_number', 'neighborhood', 'cp'];

public function lists()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin\Models\Lists', 'list_has_addresses' , 'address_id', 'list_id');
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Admin\Models\User');
}

public $timestamps = false;
}
```

**Controller Lists Addresses**

```
public function form_edit_address( $id_list, $id_address ){

        $list = Lists::find( $id_list );

        $address = ListsAddresses::find( $id_address );

        return view( "admin.forms.form_edit_address" )
                    ->with( 'list', $list )
                    ->with( 'address', $address );

    }
```

**View of Form**

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="padding-right: 0">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="order">Orden*</label>
            <input type="order" class="form-control" id="order" name="order" value="{{ $address->order }}" required>
          </div><!-- /.form-group -->
        </div><!-- /.col -->
```

My table pivot of database have the next structure

```
id - title - order - list_id - address_id
```

How I can get the value of order corresponding to the address in pivot table in my view?

EDDIT

This is the way i save the order in when i create new address

```
if( $address->save() ){

                $address_data = array();

                $address_title = htmlspecialchars( $request->input( "state" ).' '.$request->input( "city" ).' '.$request->input( "street" ).' '.$request->input( "neighborhood" ).' '.$request->input( "cp" ) );

                $address_order = $request->input( "order" );

                $address_data[ $address->id ] = array( 'title' => $address_title, 'order' => $address_order );

                $list->addresses()->attach( $address_data );
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe first change your relation function to have a `withPivot('order')`

```
public function lists()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin\Models\Lists',
        'list_has_addresses' , 'address_id', 'list_id')
       ->withPivot('order');
}
```

Next, you're fetching the $list and $address entirely separately, right now there's no guarantee they're actually related to each other.  If you're not doing Route Model binding then maybe you should have some ..OrFail() checks to abort with 404 if things aren't found:

```
public function form_edit_address( $id_list, $id_address )
{

    $address = ListsAddresses::findOrFail( $id_address );
    $list = $address->lists()->where('list_id', $id_list)->firstOrFail();

    return view( "admin.forms.form_edit_address" )
                ->with( 'list', $list )
                ->with( 'address', $address );
}
```

I think the $list object will be the one with the pivot property, so in your view you would probably say `$list->pivot->order`

Comment: Hi, i already try this and not work, give error for get data non object, i add some extra code in my question, regards.